# Is Engineering card issued by Feani recognized in USA?

Tags: civil-engineering, licensure

I am holder of Engineering card, now I moving to USA and would like to avoid at least hustle about translating all diplomas and deal with transcripts. Engineering card issued by Feani have Bachelor/Master studies listed on it, is it enough for USA, Texas to be more precise?  As i understand I can't avoid EIT and PE test even if I am registered engineer in my country but avoiding transcripts would be nice start.

Comment: What sort of work are you planning to apply for?  The vast majority of engineering jobs don't require any sort of certification, other than perhaps verification of education.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about getting your PE license in Texas, or just to get a job in an engineering field in Texas? Many jobs do not require a PE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because this question should be referred directly to the Texas Board of Professional Engineers. This is a simple question of fact where we cannot hope to maintain as accurate and current an answer as [the licensing body itself does on their website](https://engineers.texas.gov/lic_basic.htm). Since FEANI doesn't appear to be a signatory to the [Washington Accord](http://www.ieagreements.org/Washington-Accord/signatories.cfm), you may be required to submit a [foreign credential evaluation](https://engineers.texas.gov/lic_eval_toefl.htm). You may want to start this ASAP.

Comment: [Slide 14 of this presentation from 2011](http://www.ieagreements.org/Washington-Accord/Washington-Accord-Overview.pdf) says that the IEA is "Working toward recognition agreement" with EUR-ACE but I'm not finding any more current information than that. Some FEANI member countries are also Washington Accord signatories but not [the particular countries currently listed as providing Engineering Cards](http://www.feani.org/site/index.php?id=279). You may be able to request a waiver from TBPE but the only way to find out is to contact them directly.

Comment: Thank You all for answering, my main concern was about credential evaluation and if was possible to avoid it by presenting engineering card since it is expensive and complicated to get all documents from my University. Will contact TBPE first. Once again, thank You.